# Using pip 7.1.2 and Python 3.5 completely unable to install any packages

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-3.5, macos-mojave

I have a major problem preventing me from setting up my developer environment using `pip 7.1.2` and `Python 3.5` in a virtual environment. First of all, I can't even update `pip`, let alone install **any** packages, as this is always the same error:

```
(venv) ➜  venv git:(master) ✗ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

Let's try a `requirements.txt` file that contains the following:

```
pytz
django==1.11.4
```

The error produced is the same:

```
(venv) ➜  venv git:(master) ✗ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting pytz (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytz (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Maybe, it's because a version number is missing? Let's add the latest correct package version, `2019.2`, and run the install from `requirements.txt` one more time.

```
(venv) ➜  venv git:(master) ✗ pip install -r requirements.txt     
Collecting pytz==2019.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz==2019.2 (from -r deploy/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytz==2019.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Let's try `django`, with or without version numbers.

```
(venv) ➜  venv git:(master) ✗ pip install django
Collecting django
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

Comment: Try `--verbose` option to provide more information.

Comment: WOW, thank you. Caught this now: `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/: connection error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:646) - skipping`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `pip` under version `9.0.2` on OSX is incompatible with SSL certificates issued by the new `pip` servers. To updgrade `pip` manually from this situation, you need to run the following:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py`

Comment: My version of pip is 19.2.2 and i don't know if that is latest.